# Sitecore Logs shows The current user cannot be resolved from the authentication cookie

Tags: security, authentication

Sitecore logs are showing lot of these messages:  WARN  The current user cannot be resolved from the authentication cookie. The cookie will be removed.

```
Ex:
    Line 556: 1820 07:14:48 WARN  The current user cannot be resolved from the authentication cookie. The cookie will be removed.
    Line 1680: 6612 08:02:06 WARN  The current user cannot be resolved from the authentication cookie. The cookie will be removed.
    Line 1681: 6916 08:02:06 WARN  The current user cannot be resolved from the authentication cookie. The cookie will be removed.
```

We are using mixed authentication : Asp net membership provider + Sitecore virtual user. We recently upgraded from Sitecore 7.2 to Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519) and are using Mongo DB as well for gathering Analytics data.

Any suggestions to identify the issue? I verified on the server and there aren't any app pool recycles when this happened.

Comment: this might happen when the cookie can't be parsed properly. For example, you might have changed the machine key or if you have many CDs with different machine keys or your CDs are not sticky balanced.

Comment: Yes we have three CD Servers but none of them have the machine Keys in the config files and I verified that load balancer has sticky sessions enabled.

Comment: it is defined in the machine config on the instance. Check if they are the same

Comment: I would also make sure the Analytics.ClusterName is the same for all CD's

Comment: I recently dug deep into the bowels of Authentication. My main question here is how are you separating your Membership user and the Sitecore virtual user? What configuration did you change to add your Membership? I get the feeling that your authentication mechanisms may be fighting over the cookie...

Comment: @adb I added machine keys in web config file on all three servers with same key and still seeing the issue.

Comment: @PeteNavarra - Yes the Analytics Cluster name is same in all environments which is <setting name="Analytics.ClusterName" value="default-cd-cluster" patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config"/>

Comment: does default-cd-cluster resolve to a proper CD ip?  this needs to be a proper resolving hostname.

Comment: @IvanL - We verify if it's a valid user with custom membership provider and upon successful verification we bind the user as a virtual user and log them into Sitecore. We get the same user cookie using FormsAuthentication and  add/bind Sitecore roles to the user. We didn't make any config changes to Membership provider as it's not or shouldn't be aware of Sitecore. Thanks for your insight though..

Comment: @PeteNavarra - Nope it doesn't... Probably that's the issue!!! I'll change it on Tuesday and will let you know the results... Thanks much Pete..

Comment: Also I raised a ticket with Sitecore today. I'll post the response as soon as I hear back from them as well... Thanks everyone..

Comment: @Vamshi I understand that in that case you have a custom login form setup and handle everything custom there before calling the standard AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser() with the virtual user you build after verifying against your custom implementation. You don't touch the cookie yourself in other words right?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error when logged in to the Sitecore backoffice and then attempting to log into the site as a front-end member in the same browser.

I don't believe Sitecore can handle this situation gracefully by default and logs this error.

Haven't looked at the core code but likely this is likely due to multiple identities on the same auth ticket and Sitecore blindly grabbing the first.

Can you confirm if this is your scenario? Or do you see this error when logging in on separate browsers too?

Comment: I could see this error when logging in on separate browsers too... Between in CD servers we disabled Sitecore login and CM server is in a different server.